Mounting a Filesystem Isn't necessary to read from Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 Account
I have a question from my Microsoft Practice Exam that I got while purchasing my exam date. Here is the question and answer:

The explanation does not give a whole lot either:

With the references as follows:
https://docs.databricks.com/en/connect/storage/azure-storage.html
https://docs.databricks.com/en/security/secrets/secret-scopes.html
https://docs.databricks.com/en/security/secrets/secrets.html
Does anyone understand why I would need to mount a filesystem using a service principle if I just wanna read from an ADLS Gen2 account? I assume they mean the DBFS (Databrincwith this so not sure why we would need to do that. Also isn't the RDD API just the normal spark API which we have to use?

RDD API credentials are read from Hadoop configuration. This is a cluster-wide configuration distributed to all apps and worker nodes, so if you want to keep the credential secure then you shouldn't use this method.
The focus of the question is around secret scopes. Secret scopes are designed for this sort of thing, and provide such benefits as:

Scoped access
Centralised management
Automatic log masking to prevent leaks

So, mounting the file system supports data access (method of access) and using a service principal is the most secure way to do so in a workspace.
What does actually confuse me is the answer Configure the storage account key with spark.conf.set(). Yes, of course, since we should not use Hadoop configuration we should use spark config - we covered that already, but a storage account key is not required when using a service principal client secret. The method of authentication is OAuth, not account key. So I think this answer is misleading, if not completely wrong.
All in all, the purpose of the question is to test your knowledge on keeping credentials secure in ADB, using secret scopes, and how to leverage the API by mounting a filesystem.
